# When formatting my sql-insert statement from ordereddict, the data is only 1 char, not the key/value from ordereddict

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I am trying to insert an ordered dict into mysql and think I am missing one simple item.

```
sql_command = """CREATE TABLE asdf ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT(100), data_value TEXT(100));"""
cursor.execute(sql_command)
for id, p in enumerate(info):
    format_str = """INSERT INTO asdf (id, description, data_value) VALUES ({id}, '{description}', '{data_value}');"""
    sql_command = format_str.format(id=id, description=p[0], data_value=p[1])
    print(sql_command)
```

this actually does 95% of what I want however, for some reason it is only printing the first two letters of the first 'item'  so if 'info' is the data below

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'bob'), ('favorite food', 'pizza')])
```

it prints out the following

```
INSERT INTO asdf (id, description, data_value) VALUES (0, 'n', 'a');
INSERT INTO asdf (id, description, data_value) VALUES (1, 'f', 'a');
```

but I want it to print the following

```
INSERT INTO asdf (id, description, data_value) VALUES (0, 'name', 'bob');
INSERT INTO asdf (id, description, data_value) VALUES (1, 'favorite  food', 'pizza');
```

thoughts?

Comment: removed sqlalchemy - its a python/dict problem and not really related to either sqlalchemy nor mysql (left mysql b/c a sql-statement is involved) - otherwise nicely posted. Read up in [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get some tips how to debug stuff like this - by peppering in some print statements you could have found it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dictionary at hand, the `enumerate()` gives you the `index,key` of the dictionary, not the values of your dict.

```
for id, p in enumerate(info):
    format_str = """INSERT INTO asdf (id, description, data_value) VALUES ({id}, '{description}', '{data_value}');"""

    # here are changes
    sql_command = format_str.format(id=id, description=p, data_value=info[p])
```

should fix it.

Your indexing `p[0]` is the first char of your `key`, `p[1]` the second char.
 Replace it with `p` (full key) and `info[p]` (dict-access for value).

Comment: This works!  Thank you!  I played with the print statements some more for fun, much appreciated!   

side note, can you recommend some literature for additional information on playing/learning this stuff?

Comment: @username click on the [tag:python]-TAG, click on "Learn more..." - scroll all down, plenty of ressuorces. YOu could join hackerrank.com and do some pythonic solutions there, or some other kind of "learn how to code" sites. It's good enough to get into basics of a language